# An X-Mensa dq question

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, seasonal

Which of the numbers should fill in the ?.

> 4, 3, 4, 7, 0, 45, 7, 15, 64, 0, 1111, 55, 5, 5, 0, 20, 32, 1, ?

a) 2

b) 0

c) 20

d) 1

Hints:

1.

> There is a reason why the number-sequence tag was omitted.

2. 

> Where to begin... How can the first 4 numbers be relevant to the seasonal tag?

3. 

> What are 4 basic math operations?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Step 1:

> Taking `0` as the separator of the sequence to get four groups of four
>  numbers each, and concatenating these four numbers into two, we get:
>  
>  `(43, 47), (457, 1564), (111155, 55), (2032, 1?)`

Step 2:

> We can then place three of the four basic mathematical operators
>  between the complete pairs of numbers to get a seasonal result:
>  
>  `43 × 47 = 2021, 457 + 1564 = 2021, 111155 ÷ 55 = 2021`

Step 3:

> So ? is equal to 1, as when the remaining mathematical operator is
>  used on the resultant pair of numbers, we get:
>  
>  `2032 - 11 = 2021`

Happy New Year!

Comment: Nice one, I didn't expect it to take so long! Also please put some spoiler tags >!.